# Proving or disproving - composite number > 1 has a divisor d such that d <= sqrt(q

Tags: logic

I'm currently stuck on a proof that's giving me a hard time, not sure where to start:

Prove or disprove: If an integer $q \gt 1$ is composite, then $q$ will have some divisor $d \gt 1$ such that $d \lt \sqrt{q}$

Any ideas on how to approach these problems or any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $d\le\sqrt q$?

Comment: It has to be $\le$, not $<$

Comment: Unless the statement is to be disproved

Comment: @Cheese Exactly.

Comment: No, it's worded as d <... I guess that's a start then - should probably try to disprove it, thanks.

Comment: Just take $25$, as an example, then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the key idea.  Suppose, $d$ is a divisor of $q$ such that $d<\sqrt q$.  Then $q=dc$ for some integer $c$, and $d<\sqrt q$ implies $c>\sqrt q$.  So, if $q$ has no divisors less than $\sqrt q$, can we make the claim that $q$ is prime?

Comment: As another answer says, try $q=25$.

Comment: If i may ask, as I'm trying to get better at coming up with proofs, where you came up with q = dc?  Like, where does c come from?

Comment: Let use some actual numbers.  For example $4$ is a divisor of $24$, why?  Because $4\cdot 6=24$.  So, $d=4$, $q=24$, and $c=6$.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is this often the case for getting proofs started? To think about it mathematically first, then translating it into a proposition?  Thank you so much for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help, but I'm not sure what you're asking about proofs.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an example to prove that the statement is wrong. 
Take $25$. It's only prime factor is $5$. Obviously, $5 \not< 5(\sqrt{25})$.